# How to check if any multiple "wrong" booleans are true?

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop, boolean

I have a number of *phone items, under the `ArrayList`: `thePhones`, of data type `PhoneX1`.

`.moved()` returns `true` when a phone is moved.

```
for (PhoneX1 aPhone : thePhones) {
    while (!aPhone.moved()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
    System.out.println(aPhone + " Moved")
    ...
```

The above code successfully works, by waiting for `aPhone` being iterated to be moved, and outputting what's expected. However, I'd like the program to figure out when a wrong phone, of which is not equal to `aPhone`, is moved, so that the program could output something along the lines of: "Wrong phone moved, Program Terminated.", and terminate. For example, if the first phone in `thePhones` is *expected* to be moved, but any other phone is moved, then the program should terminate.

*The phones being referred to are old iPhones.*

Comment: When does a phone classify as wrongly moved? Can we see your PhoneX1 class?

Comment: @Frost `.moved()` simply refers to physically moving the phone. It is either moved or isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use streams inside the while loop to do something like:

```
thePhones.stream().filter(e -> !e.equals(aPhone)).anyMatch(PhoneX1::moved)
```

Which will return true if any of the other phones in the `List` have been moved:

```
while (!aPhone.moved()) {
    if(thePhones.stream().filter(e -> !e.equals(aPhone)).anyMatch(PhoneX1::moved)) {
       //Do something
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Fixed an issue with my own code, this now works perfectly. Thank you so much! Taught me about streams too! :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the task correctly, then you basically want to "monitor" the phone movements, and consider it as an error when they are not moved in the right order. This means that you'd have to monitor the state of each phone *individually*, assuming that the state that is returned by the `moved()` method may change at any point in time.

If this is correct, then one approach would be the following:

- Define the *expected* sequence of the phones to move (this is the sequence that they have in the list)
- For each phone, schedule a task that monitors the state of the phone
- If a task detects that the phone was moved, place it into a (blocking) queue
- Wait for each phone to be placed in the queue, and verify that they appear there in the expected order

This is implemented here, to show the basic idea. There may be caveats, depending on the polling frequency and such, but I think it could be a reasonable approach. Alternative implementations (e.g. using an `ExecutorCompletionService`) might be possible, though:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

public class PhoneMoveDetector
{
    // Dummy phone class that changes its "moved()" state after a certain time
    private static class PhoneX1
    {
        private final String name;
        private volatile boolean moved = false;

        PhoneX1(String name, long delayMs)
        {
            this.name = name;
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> 
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(delayMs);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                System.out.println("Moving " + this);
                moved = true;
            });
            t.start();
        }

        boolean moved()
        {
            return moved;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        checkRightMoveOrder();
        detectWrongMoveOrder();
    }

    private static void checkRightMoveOrder()
    {
        List<PhoneX1> phones = new ArrayList<PhoneX1>();
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("A", 1500));
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("B", 3000));
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("C", 4500));
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("D", 6000));

        MoveDetector moveDetector = new MoveDetector(phones);

        System.out.println("Checking right move order");
        for (PhoneX1 phone : phones)
        {
            try
            {
                moveDetector.waitForExpectedToMove();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Moved " + phone);
        }
    }

    private static void detectWrongMoveOrder()
    {
        List<PhoneX1> phones = new ArrayList<PhoneX1>();
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("A", 1500));
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("B", 3000));
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("C", 2000)); // Should be moved later
        phones.add(new PhoneX1("D", 6000));

        MoveDetector moveDetector = new MoveDetector(phones);

        System.out.println("Detecting wrong move order");
        for (PhoneX1 phone : phones)
        {
            try
            {
                moveDetector.waitForExpectedToMove();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Moved " + phone);
        }
    }


    private static class MoveDetector
    {
        private final Queue<PhoneX1> expectedPhones;
        private final BlockingQueue<PhoneX1> movedPhones;

        MoveDetector(List<PhoneX1> phones)
        {
            expectedPhones = new LinkedList<PhoneX1>(phones);
            movedPhones = new LinkedBlockingDeque<PhoneX1>();
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            List<Callable<Object>> observers = 
                new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
            for (PhoneX1 phone : phones)
            {
                Runnable r = () ->
                {
                    while (!phone.moved())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    movedPhones.offer(phone);
                };
                observers.add(Executors.callable(r));
            }
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> 
            {
                try
                {
                    executor.invokeAll(observers);
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e1)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            });
            t.start(); 
        }

        void waitForExpectedToMove() throws InterruptedException
        {
            PhoneX1 moved = movedPhones.take();
            PhoneX1 expected = expectedPhones.peek();
            if (!Objects.equals(expected, moved))
            {
                System.out.println("Moved " + moved + ", but expected " 
                    + expected + " - ERROR!");
                // Handle this case as desired, e.g. by doing a
                // throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Moved " + moved + ", as expected");
                expectedPhones.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is shown here:

```
Checking right move order
Moving A
Moved A, as expected
Moved A
Moving B
Moved B, as expected
Moved B
Moving C
Moved C, as expected
Moved C
Moving D
Moved D, as expected
Moved D

Detecting wrong move order
Moving A
Moved A, as expected
Moved A
Moving C
Moved C, but expected B - ERROR!
Moved B
Moving B
Moved B, as expected
Moved C
Moving D
Moved D, but expected C - ERROR!
Moved D
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like the program to figure out when a wrong phone, of which is not equal to     aPhone, is moved, so that the program could output something along the lines of: "Wrong   phone moved

Your aPhone here is actually a collection of type PhoneX1 so it is not clear how you get something that does not match the generic type of your collection.

> The phones being referred to are old iPhones.

my suggestion would rather be that int your class PhoneX1 include a boolean variable say

```
bool isOldIphone = false;
```

then from your driver you check for the type of phone wether its old or new and perform your logic

```
ArrayList<PhoneX1> oldPhones = thePhones.stream().filter(e -> e.isOldIphone);     //this returns a list of old phones
```

You can then go ahead and perform your logic like say

```
oldPhones.forEach(System.out.println("old phone moved"));
```

Comment: I'm using a library/package so don't believe that's possible

Comment: which library are you using